# I want to catch all possible android exception globally so application can't close

Tags: java, android

I want to catch all available exception cause in one class so the app isn't unexpectedly close.
I write some code for it but it doesn't work

MyApplication.java class

```
import android.app.Application;

public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private static MyApplication mInstance;
    private Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler defaultUEH;
    private Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler _unCaughtExceptionHandler =
            new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
                @Override
                public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {

                    // here I do logging of exception to a db
//                    Log.d("MyApp", "Uncaught exception.");
                    // Do what you want.

                    // re-throw exception to O.S. if that is serious and need to be handled by o.s. Uncomment the next line at that time.
                    //defaultUEH.uncaughtException(thread, ex);
                }
            };

    public MyApplication() {
        defaultUEH = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;
    }

    public static synchronized MyApplication getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

 


}
```

So how i call `_unCaughtExceptionHandler` object

Comment: are you saying you will catch all the exceptions and handle those appropriately

Comment: Generally, when you commit, Android Studio analyses everything and shows you Code Analysis and where exceptions can occur; Catching those are enough to ensure your application cannot close, globally.